# Handle Button click Generically

Tags: jquery

I have 6 buttons on the page. On every button click, I do the following:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
        $('#txt').val("+");
    }
)

$('#btn2').click(function(){
        $('#txt').val("-");
    }
)

$('#btn3').click(function(){
        $('#txt').val("*");
    }
)
```

If you observe, the functionality in each click remains the same, the only difference is a new character is added to the textbox. How can i write this generically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend delegating your event listener, to reduce code clutter. And you can make use of HTML5 data attributes and `$.data` to get the effect you desire:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="btn1" data-text="+">Button 1</button>
  <button id="btn2" data-text="-">Button 2</button>
  <button id="btn3" data-text="*">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Then in your JS file:

```
$('#buttons').delegate('button', 'click', function(e) {
  $('#txt').val($(this).data('text'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your html is formatted like this:

```
<button type="button" sign="+">Button Value</button>
```

Then you could handle it like so:

```
$('#btn1, #btn2, #btn3').click(function(){
    $('#txt').val($(this).attr('sign'));
});
```

I think this is what pimvdb was suggesting.

Edit: heh. he edited his solution before i hit the submit button

Comment: Nice way too, didn't mean that, however `sign` isn't a valid HTML4 attribute either.

Comment: if he wasn't using html5 and didn't want to use an attribute not in the spec he could do a switch in the anonymous function to set what the value of `$('#txt')` should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn1, #btn2, #btn3').click(function(){
        $('#txt').val($(this).data('sign'));
    }
)
```

and then define in HTML:

```
<input ... data-sign="+">
```

and so on.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zvPCz/.

Comment: Well, you could also just use the `attr('value')` attribute, since that's equal.

Comment: You can still make use of data attributes in HTML4, as jQuery will correctly parse these. If you use an HTML4 doctype, your HTML may not validate, but it will still work.

Comment: ok so you mean i do this? <input ... value="+">. and then read it?

Comment: if you're using value you may as well use `.val()` rather than `.attr('value')`, not that it makes much difference!